# When using FragmentActivity cant "setChecked" anything in onCreate.

Tags: android, android-fragments

Using swipe-able Fragments in the main Activity.

I am having trouble figuring out how to make a call that looks for a file, and then calls the `setChecked(boolean)` method on an Android Switch, `cb1`, based on whether the file exists or not.

I currently have it setup so that when the app starts, a popup shows and the user clicks ok and that triggers the check for the file and set checked actions.

To clarify, the actions I'm calling all **do** work as expected, unless it's in `onCreate()`.

If it's in `onCreate()`, the logcat will show a NullPointerException caused by `DeviceSetup.setup` on whichever line the first `setChecked(boolean)` is at.

`MainActivity#onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ChangeTheme.userchoice(this);
    DeviceState.startup(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

`DeviceState` class:

```
public class DeviceState extends MainActivity {
    public static void startup(final MainActivity activity) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Welcome");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Select Ok to continue");
        alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Button startup = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.startup);
                startup.performClick(); /* <<<THAT BUTTON TRIGGERS "SETUP" BELOW */
                Rooted.rooted(activity);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public static void setup(MainActivity activity) {        
        File file1 = new File("/system/app/somerandom.apk");
        if (file1.exists()) {
            cb1.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            cb1.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

`Fragments` class:

```
public class Fragments extends FragmentActivity {
    public static class FragMods extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            outState.putString("BUGFIX", "BUGFIX");
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_mods, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class FragExtras extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public FragExtras() {}

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            outState.putString("BUGFIX", "BUGFIX");
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View extrasView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_extras, container, false);
            return extrasView;
        }
    }

    public static class FragCred extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public FragCred() {}

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            outState.putString("BUGFIX", "BUGFIX");
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View creditView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_credit, container, false);
            return creditView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `cb1` declared and initialised? It's not in the parts of the code you've listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to any View objects inside a fragment should be done using View object of the fragment say in your case rootView.

// using Fragment View Object i.e rootView, find the view you want to update and do the updation.

```
Checkbox cb = (Checkbox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxId);
```

//do updates on cb

The action won't work in onCreate() of Fragment Activity, as in onCreate() method,
we have the View reference to the main activity view i.e the viewPager, which acts as container for different Fragment Views..

Comment: okay I did that but if I want to save SharedPreferences, I can't because i cant add MainActivity activity to the FragMods method

Comment: what i have done for saving shared preferences is:

    
1. Created a support class which handles SharedPreferences related code.

2. I instantiate this class any where, I wish.

http://pastebin.com/XkBQVSbt 

See the class, can be instantiated in **onCreate()**, and thus use its methods to read/write values to SharedPreferences.